# printf is using my files in the directory the script is called from

Tags: bash, shell, printf, quoting

I have a line of code
`printf "%5d%s%s%d%s" $opNum $IDLE_TEXT $LINE_ENDER $ops "."`
All the variables passed are defined, but for some ungodly reason, printf is trying to grab files in the dir the script is called from.

Example of error output:

`./asg4.sh: line 248: printf: alpha.sh: invalid number 9:1243210asg4.sh`

Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Add content of all variables to your question.

Comment: Guessing one of your vars has a `*` or some other special character in it and is matching a file, quote your vars.

Comment: @123: Need not be the case, getting the same error because of having the `.` in arguments section.

Comment: @inian, I'm basing it off the error message which appears to contain a filename, obviously anything that is not only digits will give an error for `%d`

Comment: @Cyrus They all have content associated with them.

Comment: Your answer is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to have a `.` do it as part of the output, do it as part of the `<FORMAT>` section *rather* than part of being in `<ARGUMENTS...>` section, when you think `printf` works as

```
printf <FORMAT> <ARGUMENTS...>
```

So adding `.` in the former section

```
printf "%5d%s%s%d." "$opNum" "$IDLE_TEXT" "$LINE_ENDER" "$ops"
#               ^^^  Adding the . to the <format> section
```

and double-quote all your shell variables, to avoid word-splitting by the default field-separator in shell.

---

From the comments below, it did seem because of the lack of double-quotes in the arguments was the *actual* reason for the error. In your case `*` trying to expand the folder contents.

Comment: Double quoting my variables, or lack thereof was the issue. One of the variables was a string of `*`, which is apparently a special character. Still new to the language, thanks for the help

Comment: @inian, the last arg in the format section was a string so half your answer is misleading and not even an issue.

Comment: The `.` was not an issue as they had `%s` as the last part of the format.

Comment: You don't have to do anything, was just pointing out that you highlighted the `.` as an issue when it was not, and that it may be misleading to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Globbing is performed on the (post-expansion) value of unquoted variable expansions.

The following may have other issues (depending on what values are contained), but should not cause globbing-related problems.

```
printf "%5d%s%s%d%s" "$opNum" "$IDLE_TEXT" "$LINE_ENDER" "$ops" "."
```